# pdflatex says glossary entry is undefined when it is defined

Tags: pdftex, glossaries, glossaries-extra

I am writing my thesis and for months it has been compiling without a problem. Now when I attempt to compile (I use pdflatex) it gives the following error.

```
[78 <./chapters/the_reductome/images/growth_division_and_kos.png>]
Underfull \vbox (badness 10000) has occurred while \output is active

! Package glossaries-extra Error: Glossary entry `GDS' has not been defined.

See the glossaries-extra package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.146 

? H
You need to define a glossary entry before you can reference it.
?
```

The thing is that that I have been using this glossary term for months without a problem for months (it is probably the most commonly used term). Furthermore, line 146 is a blank line.

The definition is 
    `\newacronym{gds}{GDS}{genome design suite}`

The usage is normally 
    `\gls{gds}`

The error reoccurs two more times at other blank lines (not every blank line though).

I have tried looking up-stream of the first error to see if there is any unclosed braces or equations etc but can't find anything.

I have tried pressing enter to the errors and then checking the resulting PDF. The document appears to be created with no problems as I can't find any strange behaviour caused by the errors.

I copied the main tex file of the thesis into a new directory and then modified it so that there was only one chapter tex file. In the chapter tex file I used the `\gls{gds}` glossary term with no problem and cannot find a way of recreating the error.

Can anyone please help explain this strange error, or suggest ways in which I might be able to recreate the error in a smaller example or suggest ways to better understand the problem or search for a solution to the problem? I'm completely stuck here...

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! 
In the first compilation you have to use `pdflatex -interaction=nonstopmode <FileName>` in order to get a pdf output and the first aux file... after that `pdflatex <FileName>` will use the created `.aux` file(s) and will compile without errors

Comment: you have not shown enough of the log to know which file the line 146 refers to. I would expect it has `\gls{GDS}`  rather than `\gls{gds}` either because it was entered that way or because it has been through some uppercase section handling code without being protected against uppercasing.

Comment: @koleygr `pdflatex -interaction=nonstopmode <FileName>` runs without error as you say but then if I run `pdflatex <FileName` then it errors as before. Any suggestions why that might be?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I'm not sure which bit of the log you need to see and it's a very large log. Can you expand a bit please? 

It references pictures in a specific chapter just before and just after, is this enough to know? This chapter is the one with the blank line I was talking about in the question. I did have a quick look at that line in other chapters and there was nothing obviously wrong with them.

Comment: each time a file is opened the log has `(/full/path/to/file `  and each time it is closed the log has `)` so to see which file the line number refers to work backwards up the log to find the nearest unclosed file open marker.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle whilst looking for the path as you said I found a reference to changing dropping gls on line 102. I went to line 102 and found a \gls{gds} in a section heading. I thought I had already searched for this in sections and captions but I must have missed this one. Interestingly using `glsfmttext` worked (but is not a hyperlink in the document) but  `\glsfmtlong` and `\glsfmtfull' did not fix the error.

If you want to write this as an answer then I'm happy to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The log file will confirm the file in which the problem occurs.

Assuming that you do not have a simple typo of `\gls{GDS}` the usual cause of such an error is using `\gls{gds}` in a section heading or title that is uppercased. (You see a similar problem with `\ref` in such a place.)

One way to avoid the problem is to use

```
\newcommand\glsgds{\gls{gds}}
```

in the preamble and then

```
\section{...\protect\glsgds\ ...}
```

in the heading and that (most likely, depending on how the uppercasing is implemented in your heading code) will protect the argument of `\gls` from being uppercased.